# Bringing process status to web?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a script which output the percentage of completeness : 10% 20%...100% done.

Can i bring that output to the web?
I call it using jquery ajax:

$.post('dojob.php?id=jobid');

thanks Arman

Comment: do you want to display it with a bar or something?

Comment: Does not matter.. the problem is the problem script is running like 10 seconds..each time it advances 10%...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you want, you're looking to call `dojob.php` and have it return it's progress at certain intervals.  This can't be done with one ajax call.

If you need to do this, you will have to call dojob.php but then every x seconds make a separate call to somehow monitor it's progress.  For instance, lets say you have checkStatus.php which can give you the progress of dojob.  So you call dojob.php, then every 5 seconds call checkStatus.php which will return your % complete of dojob.

Simiarly, you could call dojob and have it kick off a separate thread and then return.  THen every x seconds call checkStatus.php, which will either return the % complete, or upon completion return the result of dojob.

Comment: Thanks,Sounds reasonable. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

to simply write it, try the following code

html:

```
<div id="progress"></div>
```

js code:

```
$('#progress').load('dojob.php?id=jobid');
```

Comment: It does not work. the div will be updated when the dojob.php will finish.so no live update of process.